# How to change color of cancel button in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

When I set `barTintColor` attribute on my custom class cancel button becomes invisible! It is there but it is not visible. My minimum compatibility is iOS 8.0 so i cannot use  `appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: <#T##[UIAppearanceContainer.Type]#>)` and I also have tried looping over subviews and setting `tintColor` but that didn't work either. I cannot us `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor` because I have a toolbar in my scene and this will change the tintColor for other buttons too.

color codes are:

```
static let purpleColor =  UIColor(red: CGFloat(70.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(54.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(224.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
static let scrollBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(240.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(241.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(242.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
```

My custom class is like:

```
import UIKit

class SPSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        tintColor = Config.purpleColor
        barTintColor = Config.scrollBackgroundColor

        let cancelButton = value(forKey: "cancelButton") as! UIButton
        cancelButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), for: .normal)
        cancelButton.setTitleColor(Config.purpleColor, for: .normal)
        cancelButton.tintColor = Config.purpleColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if it helps you:

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor .red]

 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Add these lines in you **ViewDidLoad** method.

Comment: Thanks ! Have been searching all the way through ! These 2 lines fixed my issue @mumu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let cancelButtonSearchButton = searchBar.value(forKeyPath: "cancelButton") as? UIButton
    cancelButtonSearchButton?.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

This goes into the ViewController where you have set up an outlet of your UISearchBar